# Which is faster int[0] or AtomicInteger?

Tags: java, performance, java-8

Which is better if I don't care about thread-safety?

```
int[] index = {0};
index[0]++;
```

vs

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0); 
index.getAndIncrement()
```

Comment: if you are about speed over correctness to begin with... these are used in entirely different cases. but the first is way faster, in case you *really* care

Comment: If `AtomicInteger` were faster, one would imagine that the JVM would implement `int` in terms of it.  So then they'd be the same speed.

Comment: AtomicInteger uses a volatile int, which involves memory barriers & CAS operations. Quite expensive compared to normal increment operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AtomicInteger` has its name for a reason, it is atomic in case of multi-threaded access, having its access protected to be safely incremented by multiple threads (via `volatile` or barriers if you want). These have their cost obviously. It does a `CAS` operation (compare and swap and even if it is native on lots of CPU's, it's still not compared to incrementing a plain variable).

An int (or an array of ints or any non-thread-safe object) on the other hand is a plain variable, no need to synchronize access for anything; but in multi-threaded environments, it's useless (read will give incorrect results).

There is something a bit faster in *really contended environments*, called `LongAdder`, so you might want to use that.